# Create sticky footer using Css

Tags: html, css

Hello I trying to create sticky footer as described in [this](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) beatiful article. But I getting scroll bar on browser, and my footer "slides" out of screen borders. Here is my code:

Html:

```
<div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="main_menu">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            fdsfsdfsdfsd
            <div id="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#content {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -28px;
}

 #push, #footer {
    height: 28px;
     clear: both;
}
```

Can somebody help me? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a wrapper instead of targetting `#content`.

```css
html, body, #page {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -28px;
}
#push, #footer {
    height: 28px;
    clear: both;
}

#footer {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="main_menu"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">fdsfsdfsdfsd</div>
        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have some extra margin/padding on the page.. try

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the developer tools to look at the margin/padding on that region of the page.  The scrollbar is an indicator you likely have a couple of pixels border/padding somewhere that haven't been taken into account

Comment: I dont know, there is no extra margin or paddings... when I remove height: 100%; from #content, scrollbar dissapear, but footer not in the bootom of page...